# Prove that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) = \max\{\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I am trying to prove that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) = \max\{\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\}$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$. So far I know that $\text{dist}\left({x,y}\right) \leq d_1\left({x,y}\right)$ where $\text{dist}\left({x,y}\right)$ is the standard distance function in k-dimensional Euclidian space. I also know that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) \leq \text{dist}\left({x,y}\right) \leq \sqrt{k}\cdot d_1\left({x,y}\right)$. I have already proven that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) \geq 0$, that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) = 0 \iff x=y$, and that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) = d_1\left({x,y}\right)$, but I am stuck on the triangle inequality property of this particular metric. Any hints or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It might be instructive to know that this is a special case of the [$p-$norm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#The_p-norm_in_finite_dimensions), when you take $p\to\infty$.

Comment: As pointed out by yohBS, things will be easier and shorter to write  down if you prove that $\|x \|_\infty=\max |x_i|$ is a norm. Then $d(x,y)=\|x-y \|_\infty$ is automatically a distance. And it would be a pity to miss the fact that you have a normed vector space here. Note also that $d_\infty$ would be more appropriate than $d_1$.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:** For any particular $j$, we have $|x_j-z_j|\le |x_j-y_j|+|y_j-z_j|$.

Note also that for example $|x_j-y_j|\le \max|x_i-y_i|$.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, let me write up the solution properly then.

Comment: Given $x,y,z$  pick the max of $|x_j-z_j|$, use triangle inequality, use $|x_j-y_j|\le \max|x_i-y_i|$, $|y_j-z_j|\le \max|y_i-z_i|$, replace.

Answer (score 1):

Let $d_1\left({x,y}\right) = \max\{\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\}$. Since $d_1\left({x,y}\right)=\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|$ for some $j$ it is obvious that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) \geq 0$, that $d_1\left({x,y}\right) = d_1\left({y,x}\right)$, and that $d_1\left({x,y}\right)=0\iff{x=y}$. Now, by the definition of $d_1\left({x,y}\right)$ we have $\left|{x_j-y_j}\right| \leq d_1\left({x,y}\right)$ for any $j$. It follows that for any $j$ we have $$\left|{x_j-y_j}\right| \leq \left|{x_j-z_j}\right| + \left|{z_j-y_j}\right| \leq \max\{\left|{x_j-z_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\}+\max\{\left|{z_j-y_j}\right|:j=1,2,...k\}$$ Thus $$\max\{\left|{x_j-y_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\} \leq \max\{\left|{x_j-z_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\} + \max\{\left|{z_j-y_j}\right|:j=1,2,...,k\} $$ Or $d_1\left({x,y}\right) \leq d_1\left({x,z}\right) + d_1\left({z,y}\right)$, completing the proof that $d_1\left({x,y}\right)$ is a metric on $\mathbb{R}^k$.

Comment: Yes, that's the way.

Answer (score 0):

Three properties need to be checked:

*(1) $d(x,x)=0$

*(2) $d(x,y)=d(y,x)$

*(3) $d(x,z)\le d(x,y)+d(y,z)$

Usually the first two are easy to see.

So we check (3) suppose that when choose n,then the left side gets max, 
$$ ∣∣x_n−z_n∣∣ =||(x_n-y_n) + (y_n-z_n)|| \le ||x_n-y_n|| +||y_n-z_n||$$
$$\le max\{∣∣x_j−y_j∣∣:j=1,2,...,k\} + max\{∣∣y_j−z_j∣∣:j=1,2,...,k\} $$

so $d$ is metric on $R^k$